# Page_Load event not firing when using Response.Redirect()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two forms in my web application (Page1 and Page2).
Now Page1 is having a grid on whose row_command event i am going to Page2.
And on load event of Page2 i am checking a condition which if false i am going to Page1 using Response.Redirect().

Now when i am going from Page2 to Page1 the load event of Page1 is not getting fired.
i have used cache clearing and response.end ,but its not helping.
But when i am using Server.Transfer the load event of Page1 is getting fired.

Awaiting for ur response .Guys

Answer (score 0):

It should get called during Response.Redirect. Make sure there is no IsPostBack checks anywhere in the page load.